# How to keep help strings the same when applying decorators?

Tags: python, documentation, decorator

How can I keep help strings in functions to be visible after applying a decorator?

Right now the doc string is (partially) replaced with that of the inner function of the decorator.

```
def deco(fn):
    def x(*args, **kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    x.func_doc = fn.func_doc
    x.func_name = fn.func_name
    return x

@deco
def y(a, b):
    """This is Y"""
    pass

def z(c, d):
    """This is Z"""
    pass

help(y) # 1
help(z) # 2
```

In the Y function, required arguments aren't shown in the help. The user may assume it takes any arguments, while actually it doesn't.

```
y(*args, **kwargs) <= y(a, b) is desired
    This is Y

z(c, d)
    This is Z
```

I use `help()` and `dir()` a lot, since it's faster than pdf manuals, and want to make reliable document strings for my library and tools, but this is an obstacle.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this. What do you expect to be the output from the help() functions?

Comment: y and z accept no arguments. So without decorators help shows y() and z(). But with the decorator, y is shown with decorator's arguments: y(*args, **kwargs). If I have my certain list of arguments (y(param1, param2, param3)), I want the user to see them.

Comment: @culebrón: Please update the question.  Do not comment on your own question.  Update it to be unambiguous.  Please update the question.  Please change the two `"""Help String"""` values to be different from each other and show what you're really getting and what you wish it was.  Please update the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're requesting is very hard to do "properly", because `help` gets the function signature from [`inspect.getargspec`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=getargspec#inspect.getargspec) which in turn gets it from introspection which cannot directly be fooled -- to do it "properly" would mean generating a new function object on the fly (instead of a simple wrapper function) with the right argument names and numbers (and default values). Extremely hard, advanced, black-magic bytecode hacking required, in other words.

I think it may be easier to do it by monkeypatching (never a pleasant prospect, but sometimes the only way to perform customization tasks that are otherwise so difficult as to prove almost impossible, like the one you require) -- replace the real inspect.getargspec with your own lookalike function which uses a look-aside table (mapping the wrapper functions you generate to the wrapped functions' argspecs and otherwise delegating to the real thing).

```
import functools
import inspect

realgas = inspect.getargspec

lookaside = dict()

def fakegas(f):
    if f in lookaside:
        return lookaside[f]
    return realgas(f)

inspect.getargspec = fakegas

def deco(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def x(*args, **kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    lookaside[x] = realgas(fn)
    return x

@deco
def x(a, b=23):
  """Some doc for x."""
  return a + b

help(x)
```

This prints, as required:

```
Help on function x in module __main__:

x(a, b=23)
    Some doc for x.
(END)
```

Answer (score 5):

give the [decorator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) module a peek.  i believe it does exactly what you want.

```
In [1]: from decorator import decorator
In [2]: @decorator
   ...: def say_hello(f, *args, **kwargs):
   ...:     print "Hello!"
   ...:     return f(*args, **kwargs)
   ...: 
In [3]: @say_hello
   ...: def double(x):
   ...:     return 2*x
   ...:
```

and info says "double(x)" in it.